# Product Search API

Tags: python, fastapi

Develop a FastAPI endpoint for searching products.

● Accept query parameters for product name, category, and price range.

● Implement string validation for product name and category.

● Apply numeric validation for price range parameters.

● Return a list of products matching the search criteria.

● Test the API with various combinations of query parameters

I tried using query parameters, created a function to search through various products, returned a placeholder for actual search logic. I got stuck after that.

Comment: note that you're not actually asking a question. Please refer to [the docs here on how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Keep in mind that the better your question is, the better the answer you're going to get is going to be...